# Laravel, how to convert this blade {{ url(' ') }} into a normal html?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to use display image via innerHTML. In blade, usually we display image like this

`<img src="{{ url('uploads/file/'.$fur->picture) }}"`

but what about in innerHTML? Is it straightforward like this?

`pic.innerHTML="<img src="{{ url('blah/blah/' '"+value.id+"') }}"`

Comment: Is your js in a script tag in the blade file or in a separate js file?

Comment: my js is in a script tag which is also in blade file

Comment: I see youre still having a hard time understanding the difference between client side and server side processing.  You may want to take a step back and do some more research on it since this is the 3rd related question I've seen from you today that deal with the same basic fundamentals.

Comment: yes i am aware of that...i guess i have to learn thoroughly first (learning 100% from internet though) and i guess i have to spend some money for online courses. its just that i dont have people to refer to. im sorry if i caused other people if my question is too annoying...

Comment: It's fine, I just could tell you still didn't quite get it.  I think you can find some free resources on the difference between client side and server side programming and why we have both if you do some googling.  Javascript is built in to your browser, so that's why that is used to manipulate things after the server sends the response.  PHP can't manipulate anything once the response is sent because it doesn't run on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the JS in in a blade file you can should be able to do something like:

```
pic.innerHTML='<img src="{{ url('blah/blah') }}/' + value.id + '">'
```

This way the base path of the url will be compiled on the server so when it gets to the browser it will look something like:

```
pic.innerHTML='<img src="www.example.com/blah/blah/' + value.id + '">'
```

**NB**

Using the `url` function will strip any trailing `/` so you will need to add them in in your js.

Comment: give me a moment to try it :)

Comment: tried, works like a charm! thanks for the explanation as well

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP/Laravel is rendered before the data is passed to Javascript, you can use blade to echo variables into Javascript (but not the other way around).  You wouldn't be able to access Javascript variables from PHP, so you can't include `value.id` inside of the blade directive.

You'll also need to escape your quotes around src or use single quotes

```
pic.innerHTML="<img src=\"{{ url('blah/blah/') }}" + value.id + "\" />"
# or using single quotes:
pic.innerHTML='<img src="{{ url('blah/blah/') }}' + value.id + '" />'
```